# Problema con struct en C++

Tags: c++

¿Qué tipo de error u omisión estoy cometiendo en el código?

Especificamente en la sentencia `if` principal. Error el cual he resuelto comparando uno a uno los resultado, lo cual seria problematico cuando tenga que comparar mas de 3 variables.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct persona{
    string nombre, pat, mat;
};

int main(){
    persona a,b;

    b.nombre = "luz";
    b.pat = "dia";
    b.mat = "noche";

    cout<<"ingrese su nombre : ";
    cin>>a.nombre;
    cout<<"ingrese su apellido paterno : ";
    cin>>a.pat;
    cout<<"ingrese su apellido materno : ";
    cin>>a.mat;

    if(a == b)cout<<"son la misma persona.";//aqui tengo el problema. Siento de que se me olvida algo...
        else cout<<"son diferentes personas.";
```

Aquí es la forma de como lo resolvi.

```
if(a.nombre == b.nombre){
   if(a.pat == b.pat){
      if(a.mat == b.mat)cout<<"son la misma persona.";
   }
   else cout<<"son diferentes personas.";
}
else cout<<"son diferentes personas.";
```

Comment: Y ¿Cuál es el error en el código?

Comment: en el compilador que estoy usando (code::blocks 16.01) no puedo comparar directamente **a** con **b** dentro del if y tube que hacerlo de la forma en la cual escribi mas abajo

Comment: esta pregunta es mas para saber si existe alguna manera mas sencilla de hacerlo ya que caundo tenga que comparar un **struct** (si asi es como se llama) con 10 ó 20 variabbles no va a ser tan sencillo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), no se generan operadores de comparación para los tipos no aritméticos definidos por el usuario<sup>1</sup>, ya sean `struct`, `class` o `union`; así que el programador debe proporcionar dicho operador, para esto existen dos opciones:

#### Operador miembro.

Como parte de la interfaz de tu estructura, puedes añadir un operador de comparación:

```
struct persona{
    string nombre, pat, mat;

    bool operator ==(const persona &otra_persona) const{
        return nombre == otra_persona.nombre &&
               pat    == otra_persona.pat &&
               mat    == otra_persona.mat;
    }

};
```

Al añadir este operador miembro le indicas a tu compilador de qué manera quieres que se compare por equidad la instancia actual de la estructura `persona` cuando se compara contra otra del mismo tipo, el parámetro del `bool operator ==` será aquello que se ponga a la derecha de un `==` cuando a la izquierda haya una estructura `persona`.

#### Operador libre.

Puedes especificar cómo comparar tipos definidos por el usuario sin modificar su interfaz, añadiendo una función libre que reciba como parámetros los tipos a comparar, como ya ha sugerido [Arnau Castellví](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/14799/2742):

```
bool operator ==(const persona &p1, const persona &p2)
{ 
    return (p1.nombre == p2.nombre &&
            p1.pat    == p2.pat &&
            p1.mat    == p2.mat);
}
```

Por mi parte prefiero añadir el cualificador `const` en este operador pues este tipo de operación no modifica (ni debe modificar) los operandos.

Con este operador libre le indicas a tu compilador de qué manera quieres que se comparen por equidad dos instancias de la estructura `persona` cuando se encuentra a la izquierda y a la derecha de un `==`.

#### ¿Cuál escoger?.

El operador miembro y el operador libre tienen difrencias que vale la pena mencionar:

- *Miembro*: Requiere modificar la interfaz del objeto, el tipo propietario del operador miembro **siempre** estará a la izquierda del operador. Tienes acceso a los miembros privados del objeto.
- *Libre*: No requiere modificar la interfaz del objeto, puede definirse el orden de los operandos en la operación de comparación. No tienes acceso a los miembros privados del objeto<sup>2</sup>.

Para entender estas diferencias, añadiré otra clase:

```
struct empleado{
    persona per;
    string departamento;

    bool operator ==(const persona &una_persona){
        return per == una_persona;
    }
};
```

Con este operador de comparación en `empleado` tendremos la posibilidad de comparar empleados con personas **pero no al revés**:

```
persona a{"luz", "dia", "noche"}, b{"K'Thulu", "Ia", "Nfang"};
empleado e{ a, "Dominio Mundial" };

bool resultado1 = (e == a); // Verdadero!
bool resultado2 = (b == e); // Error! No se puede comparar persona contra empleado
```

Dado que el operador miembro requiere que el tipo dueño del operador esté siempre a la izquierda de la comparación, no se pueden comparar personas contra empleados... pero añadiendo un operador libre:

```
bool operator ==(const persona &una_persona, const empleado &un_empleado){
    return una_persona == un_empleado.per;
}
```

Ya se puede comparar persona (izquierda de la comparación, primer parámetro del operador libre) contra empleados (derecha de la comparación, segundo parámetro del operador libre):

```
bool resultado1 = (e == a); // Verdadero!
bool resultado2 = (b == e); // Falso!
```

---

En tu caso concreto es indiferente el uso de un operador miembro o libre, pero en otras ocasiones deberás escoger entre uno u otro... yo personalmente me decantaría por el operador libre ya que te permitirá usar la clase en contenedores (cosa que no permitiría la función de comparación libre que [suguiere el salado NaCl](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/14804/2742)) sin *contaminar* la interfaz del objeto.

---

<sup>1</sup>Dado que los enumerados son tipos definidos por el usuario pero su tipo subyacente es aritmético, el compilador compara su valor sin requerir operador de comparación.

<sup>2</sup>A no ser que se defina como función amiga.

Comment: +1 _Deberás escoger entre uno u otro_.

Comment: Si, debería escogerse entre uno u otro, ¡si no [sería ambiguo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/BiUWrrqMokqxuhta)! :O

Answer (score 2):

Creo que lo que buscas se llama "sobrecarga de operadores"

Seria redefinir el operador `==` para ese tipo de objeto, algo parecido a esto:

```
bool operator == (persona &p1,persona &p2)
{ 
    return (p1.nombre==p2.nombre&&p1.pat==p2.pat&&p1.mat==p2.mat);
}
```

Búscalo en google, no debería ser difícil encontrar información.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, no sabia de lo que estaba hacendo se llamaba "sobrecarga de operadores" y aqui otra pregunta.




¿existe alguna forma de comparar directamente las 2 variables, o solo se pede comparar de uno en uno?

Comment: La sobrecarga de operadores es justamente para lo que necesitas

Comment: @NaCl
se que es MUCHO pedir,pero...
 ¿podrias se un poco mas especifico?recien estoy aprendiendo a programar asi que hay ciertas funciones y codigos que no comprendo por mi inexperienca en el tema.

Comment: La sobrecarga de operadores sirve para especificar que va a hacer el operador con ese tipo de objeto, una vez creada la redefinición, podrás usar el == directamente entre dos objetos del mismo tipo.
Ya que sabes como se llama, mejor búscalo en internet, hay muchas web que lo cuentan muy bien.

Answer (score 2):

Vamos a evitar un tema complicado como la sobrecarga de operadores y a crear una función que nos ayude a evaluar cada valor en el struct:

```
bool equals(persona _a, persona _b)
{
    return (_a.nombre == _b.nombre) 
        && (_a.mat == _b.mat)
        && (_a.pat == _b.pat);
     // && (_a.<otravariable> == _b.<otravariable>)
}
```

Como se puede apreciar, estamos creando una función de tipo `bool` que nos evalua cada miembro dentro de la instancia de tipo `persona` que enviemos.

Para comprobar que todos los miembros son iguales, se utiliza el operador `&&` *(Y)* para enlazar condiciones.

Aplicado a tu código:

```
if(equals(a, b)) cout<<"son la misma persona."; // No deberia haber error...
```

Mientras que con la sobrecarga de operadores, es algo como lo que Arnau ha mencionado.

Al final siempre vas a comparar cada uno de los valores manualmente, pero hay procesos que permiten la simplificación de dicha comparación.

Espero te haya ayudado!